# ¿Como combinar dos entero y una cadena de texto?

Tags: java, android

Actualmente tengo el dilema de que quiero hacer una operacion determinada con diferentes signos de matematicas basicas (sumar,restar,multiplicar etc.).
Pero quiero que el signo sea el unico que cambie al hacer la operacion:

Codigo anterior

```
resultado = resultado + numero; // Este código me daba el resultado de la suma  de ambos números
```

Código actual:

```
resultado = resultado +operadores+ numero; // este código me marca error
```

La linea que me marca error ya sea a que se debe, estoy metiendo una cadena de texto dentro de una variable de tipo int con dos variables que igualmente son enteras, lo que queria realizar es sustituir el "+" que me hacia la suma por otro "+ o - o * o /" a través de la asignación a una variable y que dependiendo del botón seleccionado este me mandaría el operador necesario. La verdad no se si lo estoy desarrollando de la mejor forma pero es la única que se me ocurrió por el momento y quería ver si era capaz de hacer lo que estoy intentando. si lo convierto a cadena la variable resultado me imprimirá todo y no me dará ningún numero resultante.

Codigo completo del metodo

```
public void igualdad(View v) {

    TextView txtSI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    obtenerNS = txtSI.getText().toString().split("\\+");

    for (int i = 0; i < obtenerNS.length; i++) {
        int numero = Integer.parseInt(obtenerNS[i].trim());
        resultado = resultado +operadores+ numero;
    }

    txtSI.setText("");
    txtSI.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué valores tiene cada variable? [edit] tu pregunta y agrega los resultados que esperas obtener. Un primer vistazo pienso que quieres concatenar un string y un int *por ejemplo*, pero creo que no es lo que preguntas.

Comment: Necesitamos el código necesario para reproducir tu problema. Tal como luce, no podemos brindarte mucho detalle.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ  ya agregue todo el código de mi método para que lo pudieran ver mejor

Comment: Tal ves te sirva usar `ScriptEngine` como se menciona en esta pregunta en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tambien puedes utilizar la sentencia `switch`

```
public double calculo(operadores, numero){
    double resultado = 0;
    operadores = operadores.replace(" ", "");
    switch (operadores) {
         case "+":
             resultado = resultado + numero;
             break;
         case "-":
             resultado = resultado - numero; 
             break;
         case "*":
             resultado = resultado * numero;
             break;
         case "/":
             resultado = resultado / numero;
             break;
         default:
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operador incorrecto");
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Recuerda siempre limpiar el String de `operadores` por cualquier espacio que pudiese haber.

Para optimizar tu codigo, puedes crear una función y llamarla dentro de tu ciclo como te comente.

```
resultado = calculo(operadores, numero);
```

Comment: habia pensando en ese procesamiento, pero no se podría hacer todo en una simple linea como lo estaba planeando que solo se sustituyera la parte de en medio de mi sentencia.

Comment: Es simple, crea una funcion con mi respuesta y llamada en tu ciclo.

Comment: @David edite mi respuesta puedes ocupar una sola linea

Comment: Para el caso "/" deberás checar si el número es cero para evitar que haya una excepción de division por cero.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas hacer un tratamiento a la variable **operador**, ejemplo:

```
public float Resultado(float resultado, float numero, char operador)
{
if (operador == '+')
    resultado = resultado + numero;
else if (operadores == '-')
    resultado = resultado - numero;
else if (operadores == '*') 
    resultado = resultado * numero;
else if (operadores == '/')
  {
     if (numero!=0) 
       resultado = resultado / numero;
     else throw new IllegalArgumentException("División por 0");
  }
else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operador incorrecto");

return resultado;
}
```

De esta forma puedes resolver operaciones binarias simples
en caso de que sean compuestas utiliza notación polaca.

[https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notación_polaca_inversa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notaci%C3%B3n_polaca_inversa)

Comment: Seria mas viable utilizar **equals()** ya que se utiliza específicamente para estos casos, pero igual funciona.

Comment: el ejemplo es seudocódigo, no es java

Comment: si tambien habia pensando en ese procesamiento, pero no se podría hacer todo en una simple linea como lo estaba planeando que solo se sustituyera la parte de en medio de mi sentencia. De no ser posible pues tomaría tu respuesta como buena.